# "Select all" in Kendo MultiSelect (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I have a Kendo Grid with some custom editors, one is a [multiselect](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect). I have a cshtml file for the editor that looks like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<ManageSitesInTemplateViewModel>
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m)
    .AutoClose(false)
    .DataTextField("SiteName")
    .DataValueField("SiteId")
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<ManageSitesInTemplateViewModel>)ViewData["sites"])
)
```

It uses `BindTo`, which is data gotten from `ViewData` that is created when the page is requested. Everything works fine just as it should, no problems there.

The problem is I have been trying to implement a "select/deselect all" button using various implementations to no avail. I have a suspicion that it's because I use `BindTo`.

Here is some of the examples I have tried:

[How can we implement select All option in Kendo MultiselectFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207667/how-can-we-implement-select-all-option-in-kendo-multiselectfor)

[Kendo select/deselect all items demo](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/multiselect/how-to/selection/select-deselect-all-items)

[Kendo forums: Select All items after data is read](http://www.telerik.com/forums/select-all-items-after-data-is-read)

I can get the button to select everything correctly, but when everything is selected and I try to save the entry on the grid, the action is not fired. Nothing happens and the selection resets. Still works if I select manually.

What is going on?
Full code for the custom editor:

```
@model IEnumerable<ManageSitesInTemplateViewModel>
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m)
    .AutoClose(false)
    .DataTextField("SiteName")
    .DataValueField("SiteId")
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<ManageSitesInTemplateViewModel>)ViewData["sites"])
)

<button class="k-button" id="selectall123">Select All</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectall123").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var multiselect = $('#Sites').data("kendoMultiSelect");

            var all = $.map(multiselect.dataSource.data(), function (dataItem) {
                return dataItem.SiteId;
            });
            multiselect.value(all);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting help from Telerik's own forum, they supplied me with this solution that works. I'm just gonna quote directly from them:

> When using the `MultiSelect`'s `value()` method, the model bound to the widget will not be updated, because this method does not trigger a change event. You can bypass this by manually triggering change after selecting the items:

The code with the answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectall123").on('click', function (e) {
            // ...
             
            multiselect.value(all);
            multiselect.trigger("change");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. This is an example that worked for me.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("Config_MetricType")
    .BindTo(Model.Config_MetricTypes)
    .DataValueField("MetricTypeId")
    .DataTextField("MetricDisplayName")
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("selectAllMetrics"))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 50%", @class = "pull-left" }))
```

JavaScript function:

```
function selectAllMetrics() {
    var Config_MetricType = $("#Config_MetricType").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    var all = $.map(Config_MetricType.dataSource.data(), function (dataItem) {
        return dataItem.MetricTypeId; //DataValueField
    });
    Config_MetricType.value(all);
    Config_MetricType.trigger("change");
}
```